# How to open incoming sms from notification directly to my application's intent as textview or listview?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcast, smsmanager

I want to open incoming sms from notification directly to my application's intent , Please help I tried following code to read sms from inbox

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public static String BODY = "Test";
        public static String ADDRESS = "5556";
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            //---get the SMS message passed in---
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String str = "";            
            if (bundle != null)
            {
                //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
                for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                    str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                    str += " :";
                    str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    str += "\n";
                    ADDRESS=msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    BODY=str;

                }
                //---display the new SMS message---
                Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Comment: If I click on pending sms notification I want to open my application and show sms in my intent rather than default inbox.

Comment: The Notifications for SMS are created by the individual apps that receive the messages. You cannot alter the behavior of a Notification created by another app. You can, however, create your own SMS app that issues its own Notifications.

Comment: can you please send me some link of such example project source code?
thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't personally know of any complete SMS app examples. I've seen some linked in various comments and answers here, though, so I'd imagine you could find one relatively easily with a quick search. You could also look at the source code for the AOSP Messenger app, but it might be a little intimidating to start with.

Comment: Thanks
I found AOSP messenger app github source code too much complicated to understand due to many classes and dependency hierarchy .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a new SMS is received by your device, the android creates a intent and broadcasts the [SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents.html#SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION). What you are going to do is create an [Intent Filter](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Receiving) for the activity of your application that handles the SMS that the phone receives.

When the phone gets a new SMS message and the user clicks on the notification, she is presented with a dialog of apps that can handle this action*****. Your app should be there, and when she decides that she wants your app to handle the incoming message then you can use the [getMessagesFromIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents.html#getMessagesFromIntent(android.content.Intent)) method in order to extract the message (you use that method inside your app).

PS: You cannot set your app as the default message app, which you probably need to do. The user has to explicitly choose your app to open the message, and if she wants it to be the default messaging app (by ticking the `set as default` checkbox).

**Note**: It looks like you have to create a broadcast receiver that receives the `SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION` which you can use prior to API 19 as a constant at `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` and launch your own notifications in which you direct the user directly to the application of yours. Unfortunately it seems that the default messaging app will [still](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28561494/how-to-open-incoming-sms-from-notification-directly-to-my-applications-intent-a/28593678?noredirect=1#comment45513512_28593678) issue notifications.

**Credit: [@Mike M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m)**.

Comment: No, it's available from API level 19 and up. I cannot seem to find a way for you to do this on API 15 since from what I can understand you cannot change the default sms app for reading and manipulating sms messages from API 19 and below. But I might be **wrong** about this, so I'll keep digging for a while.

Comment: Okay thanks for help George, Let me know if you find how to do this task in API 15 apps

Comment: @chinmay_92 I'll clarify a few things, here. `SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION`, as a class constant, has only been available since API 19, but prior to that, you can just use its value directly: `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED`. Also, before API 19, there was no concept of a default SMS app; you could have as many SMS apps as you wanted, each with full functionality.

Comment: @GeorgeD I wanted to mention that what you're describing doesn't sound like standard behavior. Normally, the native SMS app is responsible for issuing Notifications upon SMS receipt, and those would open the native app directly. That's why it used to be possible to intercept and abort incoming SMS and their Notifications. Of course, vendors are free to change Android's behavior all they want, so you might be describing a specific vendor's version.

Comment: @MikeM. is right. Probably the OP's application should listen for the broadcast and issue it's own notifications that will directly launch the activity necessary in his app. (Will update my answer with your remarks).

Comment: @GeorgeD You might also mention that if the OP doesn't want the native app's Notification also to appear, they will need to set a high priority on the Intent Filter (max is 999), and abort the broadcast in their Receiver's `onReceive()` method. Of course, this won't work in KitKat or above, since that broadcast can no longer be aborted, and the default app listens for a different one anyway.

Comment: @MikeM.@GeorgeD can you please provide some code snipet(test eg) or steps required to abort broadcast and launch app and open sms into our activity?